# Can I calculate loss dynamically during every session with tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

In tensorflow, can I do:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in batch_loop:
        batch_input, batch_label = getBatchData()
        batch_output = sess.run(output, feed_dict={input: batch_input})

        # calculate the loss based on the batch_output and batch_label
        loss = getLoss(batch_output, batch_label)
        grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
        opt_operation = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
        sess.run(opt_operation)
```

Can we do something like these ? I can not pre-define the loss function until I get the real output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `tf.placeholder` to pre-define your loss function, and feed them when you get the real output `batch_output` and `batch_label`.
For more information, see [tf.placeholder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that. But my problem is that the my loss function is heavily based on the real value of batch_output. So, it is very hard to pre-define the loss function. Is it possible to do something like: get the real value of batch_output, calculate the loss based on the batch_output and batch_label which will give us a constant tensor which float value, and apply apply_gradients with the optimizer ?